# NameError: name 'module2' is not defined

Tags: python, python-import

Структура проекта:

```
project
|- main.py
|- folder1
   |- module1.py
   |- module2.py
```

В module1.py:

```
import module2

# my code
```

я пишу в main.py:

```
import folder1.module1

module1.hello_world()
```

и запускаю:

```
NameError: name 'module2' is not defined
```

Даже если импортировать так:

```
# main.py:

from folder1 from *
```

Он  выдаст:

```
NameError: name 'module2' is not defined
```

как мне не добавляя полный путь или относительный - т.е без такой галиматьи:

```
# module1.py

import folder1.module2

# my code
```

спокойно импортировать только module1 не дописывая дополнительно путь как в примере выше?

У меня там просто оооочень много модулей которые зависят друг от друга и каждому полный путь переписывать не хотелось бы. Ведь если импортировать стандартные пакеты, то путь у зависимых модулей прописывать не требуется. Как-то так.

Если я сделаю папку folder1 пакетом python я решу этот вопрос?

Comment: «без такой галиматьи» — никак, способ «без галиматьи» специально удалили ещё в Python 3.0, потому что он плохой

Comment: А о том, как Python ищет модули, можно почитать например тут https://tproger.ru/translations/guide-into-python-imports

Comment: В module1.py несложно написать `from . import module2, module3, module4`

Comment: Так там так и написано в ральном коде, но это так не работает (

Comment: "т.е без такой галиматьи: import folder1.module2" - это правильный способ импорта внутри пакета. Второй вариант - относительный импорт через `import .module2` (точка тут обозначает, что импортировать модуль нужно из того же пакета, где находится текущий модуль). Дописывание чего-то в sys.path - в 99% случаев костыль, в том числе и вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло следующие:

```
# main.py:

import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'folder1'))
```

Это добавляет новый относительный путь для поиска модулей - и не важно, где находиться папка с проектом. Правда если эти модули работают с локальными файлами (читают и пишут в них), то выдаст ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "example.txt"
```

---

Вот что я понял, для python есть папки и пакеты, хотя это по сути одно и тоже, python не увидит модуль если просто поменять директорию(папку) вот так:

```
# Пример 1:
os.chdir('folder1')
```

но если сделать то же самое, но указать интерпретатору python пакет указав, где искать модули:

```
# Пример 2:
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'folder1'))
```

То о чудо, он увидит модуль и все модули в директории folder1 и не важно откуда запущен скрипт и где лежат папки проекта. Правда нужно при каждом запуске добавлять относительный путь заново!

Если просто добавить в sys.path относительный путь, то следует сменить директорию, как указано в примере 1, иначе модули в folder1 не смогут читать и писать в файлы в своей директории, ведь там указано:

```
open("example.txt") # относительный путь!
```

и чтобы не писать:

```
open("folder1/example.txt")
```

Для каждого вызова open(), можно просто вместе с примером 1 использовать пример 2!!!

И таким образом модули в folder1 даже трогать не придётся!!! Это и решило полностью мой вопрос!!!

Comment: Но делать так плохо. Особенно если вдруг названия файлов в folder1 случайно совпадут с названиями других Python-модулей (тут на сайте целая куча вопросов, вызванных случайным совпадением названий)

Answer (score 0):

наверное это делается так:

```
from folder1 import module1
```

точно уже не помню, но если вспомню, поправлю свой вариант

Comment: увы, я написал же, что это не работает, в своём ответе объясню почему.